# Cormen's Introduction to algorithms - reductions - is the proof correct?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

The theorem says: Suppose we got a problem A with no poly-time algorithm. If we can reduce it in polynomial time to problem B, then no poly-time algorithm solving B exists.

The proof can be found in Cormen's "Introduction to algorithms", chapter 34 in 3rd edition.

As we can see, two assumptions have been made here:

a) there exists no polynomial-time algorithm solving A

b) there exists polynomial-time reduction algorithm from A to B

This theorem has been proved by assuming that there exists a poly-time algorithm for B, which lead to contradiction. However, what if the contradiction results from the fact that our assumption b) was incorrect?
I'm having doubts here because all the theorem says is: if problem A is hard, and we can quickly transform it to problem B, then B is hard as well, which is not a very intuitive conclusion. Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: "if problem A is hard, and we can quickly transform it to problem B, then B is hard as well, which is not a very intuitive conclusion" The premise is that we can transform an instance of  A into an instance of B such that the solution the B-instance implies a solution for the A-instance. So if we can solve B, we can also solve A. Thus, B must be hard too.

Comment: Can we actually use this method to disprove that there is no polynomial algorithm for A? If we could prove that there exists a poly-time reduction from A to B and a polynomial algorithm for solving B, then it would be the case I guess.

Comment: Yes if you prove that B is "easy" and A reduces to B, then A is also "easy".

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136657/algorithm-clrs-solution-more-in-depth-discussion-need